Notification Actions Not Displayed When App is in Background or Killed
I am working on implementing FCM notifications in my Android app. The notifications include action buttons (Accept and "Reject"). When my app is in the foreground, the notifications with action buttons are displayed correctly. However, when my app is in the background or killed, the notification is received, but the action buttons are missing — only the title and content body are displayed.
The notification should display the action buttons even when the app is in the background or killed.
What I’ve tried:

Ensuring that the data payload contains the necessary information.
Setting the notification priority to high.

What could be causing the action buttons to not appear when the app is in the background or killed, and how can I ensure that they are displayed?
Here is the data message I am sending:
{
    "message": {
        "token": "",
        "data": {
            "title": "Urgent Alert",
            "body": "This is a high priority message.",
            "button_action": "accept",
            "button1_action": "reject"
        },
        "android": {
            "priority": "HIGH",
            "notification": {
                "channel_id": "channel1",
                "title": "test",
                "body": "message."
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is the relevant part of my FCMMessagingService.kt code:
val intent = Intent(this, SplashScreen::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    0,
    intent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
val openIntent = Intent(this, BottomNavigationBarActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("ACTION_TYPE", "OPEN")
}
val openPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    2,
    openIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
val closeIntent = Intent(this, BottomNavigationBarActivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("ACTION_TYPE", "CLOSE")
}
val closePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    this,
    1,
    closeIntent,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
)
val bigTextStyle = NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText("Long text that exceeds normal notification limits.")
val title: String = remoteMessage.notification!!.title.toString()
val message: String = remoteMessage.notification!!.body.toString()

val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHECK_IN_CHECK_OUT_ACTIONS)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(message)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon_notification)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setStyle(bigTextStyle)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
    .addAction(R.drawable.accept, "Accept", openPendingIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.reject, "Reject", closePendingIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build()
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        this,
        Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
) {
    notificationManager?.notify(0, notification)
}

